# Как создать колонку с наиболее часто встречающимися значениями другой колонки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо создать колонку `Temp` для размещения в ней значения из колонки 'Net', наиболее часто встречающегося для каждого значения из колонки 'Address':

```
d = {'name': ['rick, mike, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'rick, morty'],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'],
     'Address': ['BY', 'YU', 'RU', 'BY', 'BY'], 'Net': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]}
```

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

Ответ должен выглядеть как:

| Address | Temp |
| --- | --- |
| BY | 1 |
| YU | 0 |
| RU | 1 |
| BY | 1 |
| BY | 1 |

Comment: "для размещения в ней значения из колонки 'Net', наиболее часто встречающегося для каждого значения из колонки 'Address'" ---не могли бы Вы более развернуто описать алгоритм действий?

Comment: Ищем все значения из колонки "Address" по порядку: начнём с BY - для BY значения колонки 'Net'  равны 1, 0, 1. Наиболее часто встречается значение 1- запишем его для всех BY в колонке 'Temp'. Продолжим для каждого значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант через *transform* и *mode*

```
df['temp'] = df.groupby('Address')['Net'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])

>>> df

                 name           Date       Address Net temp
0          rick, mike, morty  11/05/2011      BY    1     1
1           tot, piter, carl   9/02/2010      YU    0     0
2                brick, nick   1/01/2014      RU    1     1
3  rick, reaven, bart, homer  12/20/2020      BY    0     1
4                rick, morty   9/30/2009      BY    1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, можно короче, но вот рабочее решение через `lambda` и `value_counts`:

```py
temp = df.groupby('Address')['Net'] \
    .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().keys()[0]) \
    .rename('Temp')
df = df.join(temp, on='Address')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Temp'] = [df['Net'][df[df['Address'] == df['Address'][i]].index].max()\
              for i in range (0, len(df['Address']))]
print(df)
```

У меня так получилось.

Comment: Циклы в Pandas это не очень хорошо всё-таки. Тут не много значений и сойдёт, а будет если много, то всё будет очень медленно и печально.

Comment: Ну я все равно решил отметиться, так как долго придумывал) Генератор списков использовал, так как читал, что он быстрее обычного цикла.